# How to get "add missing properties" suggestion when creating an anonymous object literal in VSCode and Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, autosuggest, object-literal

Given a Typescript interface Foo, which has a property which is of interface Bar:

```
export interface Foo{
   bar:Bar;
}

export interface Bar{
  text:String;
}
```

when creating an object conforming to that interface VSCode will give me a suggestion to autocomplete missing properties:

```
var foo : Foo = {
}
```

becomes:

```
var foo : Foo = {
  bar: undefined
}
```

Now I would like to define the bar property:

```
var foo : Foo = {
  bar: {}
}
```

and VSCode gives me a warning:
Property 'text' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Bar

but does not offer an option to create the missing property for me, as it did before.

Can I get this to work somehow? Or does this autocomplete feature only work when defining a named variable with declared type? This would be very useful for large, deeply nested interfaces.

Comment: Are you prompting autocompletion inside the `bar: {}` braces?

Comment: @vr. no. While I agree that that's a good workaround and would just suggest them to use that, if I understand correctly, the asker is expecting VS Code + TypeScript support to provide a similar "add missing properties" Quick Fix.

Comment: @vr. the other commenter is correct. I can use suggestions, but there is no option to automatically "scaffold" all properties at once.